# How to sum together all values associated with duplicates in list of lists?

Tags: python, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a following list:

```
x = [['A', 300], ['C', 200], ['B', 1500], ['A', 1000], ['C', 1000]]
```

Now I want to generate a new list in which the format is similar, but all the integers of duplicate strings in the list of lists are summed together. My desired result would be:

```
x2 = [['A', 1300], ['B', 1500], ['C', 1200]]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Since the end result is like a dictionary, you can use a dictionary to make it.

```
import collections

x = [['A', 300], ['C', 200], ['B', 1500], ['A', 1000], ['C', 1000]]

d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, v in x:
    d[k] += v

x2 = d.items()
# Or list(d.items()) if you really need a list
# And list(map(list, d.items())) if you need a list of
# lists, and not a list of tuples.
```